# BouncyCastle implementation with X509Certificate signing, KeyStore generation, and Socket creation

Tags: java, security, cryptography

The following is a (somewhat messy) implementation of the [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) cryptography library. I create a self-signed certificate (hopefully correctly), store it in a Java KeyStore, and use it to create an SSL (TLSv1.2) socket session. I am not concerned about efficiency, as this was mainly a proof of concept code to familiarize myself with the library and handle data cryptography in Java.

I mainly want this code to be reviewed from a security standpoint, and whether I am making safe habits or not. If there are any major errors in either security or code usage, feedback would be appreciated.

**Main** (Used for testing)

```
//Copyright (C) Leejae Karinja 2016 

import java.net.Inet4Address;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Server s = new Server(13579);
                s.start();
                s.sendData("Hello, World!".getBytes());
                s.stop();
            }
        }.start();
        new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    Client c = new Client(Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), 13579);
                    c.start();
                    System.out.println(new String(c.receiveData()));
                    c.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
        return;
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
//Copyright (C) Leejae Karinja 2016 

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.bc.BcX509ExtensionUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

public class Server {

    private int port;
    private byte[] nonce;
    private byte[] keyData;
    private SSLSocket client;
    private SSLServerSocket server;
    private DataOutputStream writer;
    private DataInputStream reader;

    private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA512withECDSA";
    private static final String KEY_GENERATION_ALGORITHM = "ECDH";
    private static final String SSL_CONTEXT = "TLSv1.2";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_INSTANCE = "JKS";
    private static final String KMF_INSTANCE = "PKIX";
    private static final Date BEFORE = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5000);
    private static final Date AFTER = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 600000);

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    Server() {

    }

    /**
     * Constructor with specified port
     * 
     * @param port Port to start the server on
     */
    Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a one time use secure random number to be used as the password
     * for a keystore
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void genNonce() {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        this.nonce = new byte[2048];
        rand.nextBytes(nonce);
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a one time use keystore for use with an SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void genKeystore() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_GENERATION_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER_NAME);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            X509Certificate cert = createCACert(keyPair.getPublic(), keyPair.getPrivate());

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(null, (new String(this.nonce)).toCharArray());
            byte[] tempPass = new byte[2048];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(tempPass);
            ks.setKeyEntry("foo.bar", keyPair.getPrivate(), new String(tempPass).toCharArray(), new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { cert });
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ks.store(os, (new String(this.nonce)).toCharArray());
            this.keyData = os.toByteArray();
            //System.out.println("Server Key Data: " + new String(this.keyData));
            //System.out.println("Server Public Cert Key: " + cert.getPublicKey());
            //System.out.println("Server Public Key: " + keyPair.getPublic());
            //System.out.println("Server Private Key: " + keyPair.getPrivate());
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Create a certificate to use by a Certificate Authority
     * 
     * Retrieved from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder&method=addExtension
     * 
     * @param publicKey Public key
     * @param privateKey Private key
     * @return Generated X509 Certificate
     */
    private X509Certificate createCACert(PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        X500Name issuerName = new X500Name("CN=127.0.0.1, O=FOO, L=BAR, ST=BAZ, C=QUX");

        X500Name subjectName = issuerName;

        BigInteger serial = BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextInt());

        X509v3CertificateBuilder builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(issuerName, serial, BEFORE, AFTER, subjectName, publicKey);
        builder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, createSubjectKeyIdentifier(publicKey));
        builder.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(true));

        KeyUsage usage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.keyCertSign | KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.dataEncipherment | KeyUsage.cRLSign);
        builder.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, usage);

        ASN1EncodableVector purposes = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_serverAuth);
        purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth);
        purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.anyExtendedKeyUsage);
        builder.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new DERSequence(purposes));

        X509Certificate cert = signCertificate(builder, privateKey);
        cert.checkValidity(new Date());
        cert.verify(publicKey);

        return cert;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method
     * 
     * Retrieved from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.cert.bc.BcX509ExtensionUtils
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static SubjectKeyIdentifier createSubjectKeyIdentifier(Key key) throws Exception {
        ASN1InputStream is = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(key.getEncoded()));
        ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo info = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(seq);
        return new BcX509ExtensionUtils().createSubjectKeyIdentifier(info);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method
     * 
     * Retrieved from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=mockserver-master/mockserver-core/src/main/java/org/mockserver/socket/KeyStoreFactory.java
     * 
     * @param certificateBuilder
     * @param signedWithPrivateKey
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static X509Certificate signCertificate(X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder, PrivateKey signedWithPrivateKey) throws Exception {
        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).setProvider(PROVIDER_NAME).build(signedWithPrivateKey);
        return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certificateBuilder.build(signer));
    }

    /**
     * Sets the port for the server to start on
     * 
     * @param port Port to start the server on
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    protected void start() {
        try {
            if (this.nonce == null) this.genNonce();
            if (this.keyData == null) this.genKeystore();

            if (this.server == null) this.startConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Stopps the SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    protected void stop() {
        this.nonce = null;
        this.keyData = null;
        this.endConnection();
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void startConnection() {
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_INSTANCE);
            ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.keyData), (new String(this.nonce).toCharArray()));

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KMF_INSTANCE);
            kmf.init(ks, (new String(this.nonce).toCharArray()));

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(SSL_CONTEXT);
            context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = context.getServerSocketFactory();

            this.server = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(this.port);
            this.server.setEnabledCipherSuites(this.server.getSupportedCipherSuites());//new String[]{CIPHER});
            this.server.setEnabledProtocols(this.server.getSupportedProtocols());

            this.client = (SSLSocket) this.server.accept();
            this.client.startHandshake();

            this.writer = new DataOutputStream(this.client.getOutputStream());
            this.reader = new DataInputStream(this.client.getInputStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Ends the SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void endConnection() {
        try {
            this.writer.close();
            this.reader.close();
            this.server.close();
            this.client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Sends data to the client
     * 
     * @param data Data to send to the client as a byte array
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    public void sendData(byte[] data) {
        try {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                this.writer.writeByte(data[x]);
            }
            this.writer.writeByte(-1);
            this.writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Receives data from the client
     * 
     * @return Returns data received from the client as a byte array
     */
    public byte[] receiveData() {
        try {
            List<Byte> dataRead = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            byte temp = this.reader.readByte();
            while (temp != (-1)) {
                dataRead.add(temp);
                temp = this.reader.readByte();
            }
            Byte[] data = new Byte[dataRead.size()];
            data = dataRead.toArray(data);
            byte[] dataFinal = new byte[data.length];
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                dataFinal[x] = data[x].byteValue();
            }
            return dataFinal;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
//Copyright (C) Leejae Karinja 2016

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.bc.BcX509ExtensionUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

public class Client {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private byte[] nonce;
    private byte[] keyData;
    private SSLSocket server;
    private DataOutputStream writer;
    private DataInputStream reader;

    private static final String PROVIDER_NAME = BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME;
    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
    private static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA512withECDSA";
    private static final String KEY_GENERATION_ALGORITHM = "ECDH";
    private static final String SSL_CONTEXT = "TLSv1.2";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_INSTANCE = "JKS";
    private static final String KMF_INSTANCE = "PKIX";
    private static final Date BEFORE = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 5000);
    private static final Date AFTER = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 600000);

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    Client() {

    }

    /**
     * Constructor with specified host and port
     * 
     * @param host Host to connect to
     * @param port Port to connect to
     */
    Client(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a one time use secure random number to be used as the password
     * for a keystore
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void genNonce() {
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        this.nonce = new byte[2048];
        rand.nextBytes(nonce);
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a one time use keystore for use with an SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void genKeystore() {
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_GENERATION_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER_NAME);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            X509Certificate cert = createCACert(keyPair.getPublic(), keyPair.getPrivate());

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(null, (new String(this.nonce)).toCharArray());
            byte[] tempPass = new byte[2048];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(tempPass);
            ks.setKeyEntry("foo.bar", keyPair.getPrivate(), new String(tempPass).toCharArray(), new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { cert });
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ks.store(os, (new String(this.nonce)).toCharArray());
            this.keyData = os.toByteArray();
            //System.out.println("Client Key Data: " + new String(this.keyData));
            //System.out.println("Client Public Cert Key: " + cert.getPublicKey());
            //System.out.println("Client Public Key: " + keyPair.getPublic());
            //System.out.println("Client Private Key: " + keyPair.getPrivate());
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Create a certificate to use by a Certificate Authority
     * 
     * Retrieved from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder&method=addExtension
     * 
     * @param publicKey Public key
     * @param privateKey Private key
     * @return Generated X509 Certificate
     */
    private X509Certificate createCACert(PublicKey publicKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        X500Name issuerName = new X500Name("CN=127.0.0.1, O=FOO, L=BAR, ST=BAZ, C=QUX");

        X500Name subjectName = issuerName;

        BigInteger serial = BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextInt());

        X509v3CertificateBuilder builder = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(issuerName, serial, BEFORE, AFTER, subjectName, publicKey);
        builder.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, createSubjectKeyIdentifier(publicKey));
        builder.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(true));

        KeyUsage usage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.keyCertSign | KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.dataEncipherment | KeyUsage.cRLSign);
        builder.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, usage);

        ASN1EncodableVector purposes = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_serverAuth);
        purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth);
        purposes.add(KeyPurposeId.anyExtendedKeyUsage);
        builder.addExtension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new DERSequence(purposes));

        X509Certificate cert = signCertificate(builder, privateKey);
        cert.checkValidity(new Date());
        cert.verify(publicKey);

        return cert;
    }

    /**
     * Helper method
     * 
     * Retrieved from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.bouncycastle.cert.bc.BcX509ExtensionUtils
     * 
     * @param key
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static SubjectKeyIdentifier createSubjectKeyIdentifier(Key key) throws Exception {
        ASN1InputStream is = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(key.getEncoded()));
        ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo info = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(seq);
        return new BcX509ExtensionUtils().createSubjectKeyIdentifier(info);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method
     * 
     * Retrieved from http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=mockserver-master/mockserver-core/src/main/java/org/mockserver/socket/KeyStoreFactory.java
     * 
     * @param certificateBuilder
     * @param signedWithPrivateKey
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static X509Certificate signCertificate(X509v3CertificateBuilder certificateBuilder, PrivateKey signedWithPrivateKey) throws Exception {
        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).setProvider(PROVIDER_NAME).build(signedWithPrivateKey);
        return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(PROVIDER_NAME).getCertificate(certificateBuilder.build(signer));
    }

    /**
     * Sets the host to connect to
     * 
     * @param host Host to connect to
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the port to connect to
     * 
     * @param port Port to connect to
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Starts the SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    protected void start() {
        try {
            if (this.nonce == null) this.genNonce();
            if (this.keyData == null) this.genKeystore();

            if (this.server == null) this.startConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Stopps the SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    protected void stop() {
        this.nonce = null;
        this.keyData = null;
        this.endConnection();
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void startConnection() {
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_INSTANCE);
            ks.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(this.keyData), (new String(this.nonce).toCharArray()));

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KMF_INSTANCE);
            kmf.init(ks, (new String(this.nonce).toCharArray()));

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(SSL_CONTEXT);
            context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

            SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();

            this.server = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(this.host, this.port);
            this.server.setEnabledCipherSuites(this.server.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            this.server.setEnabledProtocols(this.server.getSupportedProtocols());
            this.server.startHandshake();

            this.writer = new DataOutputStream(this.server.getOutputStream());
            this.reader = new DataInputStream(this.server.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Ends the SSL session
     * 
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    private void endConnection() {
        try {
            this.writer.close();
            this.reader.close();
            this.server.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Sends data to the server
     * 
     * @param data Data to send to the server as a byte array
     * @return Returns void on completion
     */
    public void sendData(byte[] data) {
        try {
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                this.writer.writeByte(data[x]);
            }
            this.writer.writeByte(-1);
            this.writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Receives data from the server
     * 
     * @return Returns data received from the server as a byte array
     */
    public byte[] receiveData() {
        try {
            List<Byte> dataRead = new ArrayList<Byte>();
            byte temp = this.reader.readByte();
            while (temp != (-1)) {
                dataRead.add(temp);
                temp = this.reader.readByte();
            }
            Byte[] data = new Byte[dataRead.size()];
            data = dataRead.toArray(data);
            byte[] dataFinal = new byte[data.length];
            int x = 0;
            for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                dataFinal[x] = data[x].byteValue();
            }
            return dataFinal;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In general just using `printStackTrace` to handle exceptions is not
  good practice.  If you don't care about handling it, just don't catch
  it.
- `return` at the end of a method is unnecessary.
- For string data using plain `getBytes`/the plain `String` constructor
  instead of specifying e.g. UTF-8 as the encoding seems more risky for
  no benefit.  I guess the platform default is useful in some
  circumstances, but sending data over the network is not one of them.
- The port number should be a constant.
- The default empty constructor that doesn't set the port number seems
  not useful.
- Streams' `close` methods should be called no matter what, that is, use
  `try`/`finally` to ensure closing resources.

Sending the data as a sequence terminated by `-1` will break immediately
once you send a general purpose file, instead send the length first or
escape the offending pattern in all sent data.

Also it would be good to use a shared class for the shared methods.

Unfortunately without a deep look into the documentation I can't say
anything about the crypto part.  You might want to ask on the
[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site as well.
In any case, if you really want to implement this yourself maybe try to
run each of the client and server against a second implementation using
an established library and compare.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made some edits, namely code cleanup and resource handling like you suggested. Thank you for your feedback!